# Any way to visualize the transform origin point in CSS?

Tags: css, animation, rotation, transform

I'm trying to make an object move along an arc, for which I need to set the `transform-origin` point away from the object itself and then `rotate` it. So instead of blindly moving the `transform-origin` point using different lengths and then finally achieving the desired result through trial and error, is there a way to make the point visible to make the process easier?

Answer (score 12):

You could add a helper with CSS. Just add following snippet to the element you set your transform-origin property to, where the `x` value for transform-origin is same as the `left` value for the helper and `y` value is same as `top` value.

```
.foo {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.foo::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #f0f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder that `::after` doesn't work on img elements.

Comment: This doesn't work for transform-origin adjustments in the Z direction.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I use to visualize **transform-origin**. Try to change **transform-origin** value on a **DIV** element. You will see a semitransparent point adjusted. The drawback of this method is that you have to set **position: relative** to a parent element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0.001);
  transform-origin: inherit;
}

span::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,128,128,0.75);
  transform: scale(1000);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**transform-origin** is necessary for **scale** and **rotation** transformations only. The meaning of it for **scale** is a point where an object is growing from (for scale-in) or a point where an object should be shrinked to (for scale-out). So, at first I shrink a **SPAN** to almost zero size, then I grow a semitransparent element (**SPAN::AFTER**) from this point.

https://codepen.io/vbarbarosh/pen/eaQLeJ

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't too happy with given answers, so I tried this:

Html:

```
<div>
  <span class="x-axis"></span>
  <span class="y-axis"></span>
</div>
```

And css:

```
:root {
    --x-origin: 85.36%;
    --y-origin: 85.36%;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ccc;
    transform-origin: var(--x-origin) var(--y-origin);
    animation: rotate 4000ms linear infinite;
}

.y-axis {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transform-origin: inherit;
    transform: translate(0%, var(--y-origin)) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 89.4deg);
    background: rgba(255,128,128,0.75);
}

.x-axis {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transform-origin: inherit;
    background: rgba(128,128,255,0.75);
    transform: translate(var(--x-origin), 0%) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 89.4deg);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/soringfs/pen/rNaGwbX?editors=1100)

The main idea is to get the posibility to visualize projected animation of any element by placing those two spans inside of it. The target element content should be commented during test.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the origin of a transform is "50% 50%", which is exactly in the center of any given element. Changing the origin to "top left" (as in the demo above) causes the element to use the top left corner of the element as a rotation point.

Values can be lengths, percentages or the keywords top, left, right, bottom, and center.

The first value is the horizontal position, the second value is the vertical, and the third value represents the position on the Z axis. The third value will only work if you are using 3D transforms, and it cannot be a percentage.

```css
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
    
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div2 {
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #454545;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin: 20% 40%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform-origin: 0px 0px; /* 0,0 indicates top left corner*/
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

For further [refrence](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/)

Comment: here in my example transform-origin in set to (0,0) thats why you get rotation at top-left ie 0,0.Isnt it visualised

Comment: I want the `transform-origin` point to be an _actual visible point_ on the screen. Here, you're showing how using different values for `transform-origin` affects the way the grey shape is rotated by manually drawing a box around it. I already know how `transform-origin` works and all the different values that it can take; I just want a visible cue to help this process.